# Curl send Firebase notification show status of success but actually no notification received

Tags: firebase, curl, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have sent a notification to the device by using CURL like below:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key=[My-server-key]" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"notification\": {\"title\": \"[Title]\",\"body\": \"[Body]\",\"icon\": \"[Icon]"},\"to\": \"<device registration id>\",\"priority\": \"high\"}" "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"
```

It works fine and is able to receive the notification after the device's user leave the site in about 1 day. But if the user leave the site without going back to the site more than about 3 days, even a month or above, the user won't get any notification anymore but the status of the response still shows success, like below:

```
{"multicast_id":5116522089453611342,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1540623541914478%e609af1cf9fd7ecd"}]}
```

How can the device be able to receive the notification even if the user leave the site without going back to the site more than 3 days?

Comment: Since you mention "site", I assume you're using a browser-based client. In that case, did you check how long the browser you're using will remain open to showing notifications? If FCM acknowledges that it received the message, the most likely reason you're not seeing it is in the client.

Comment: How can I check how long the browser I'm using will remain open to showing notifications?